# My (windows) PC is giving me the black screen of death after a power outage

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, bsod

As the title says, my computer is just a black screen when I boot it up. This problem started after the power went out when the PC was on, and it was only out for about 10 seconds. I tried turning the computer back on, and it did turn on, but was stuck booting up. It took about 40 minutes to get me to the windows sign in screen, when it normally takes about 5 seconds to boot up. (Also, during the boot up process I got the message "scanning and repairing drive :D") After I signed in, I was greeted with a completely black screen, with only my mouse cursor. None of the keyboard shortcuts I tried to use worked, EXEPT for Ctrl+Alt+Del. I was able to use that to open task manager, which, for the most part, works, but it is also (I don't know the term) cloning itself onto the background forever (I will attach a photo). Nothing out of the ordinary was on task manager, apart from my SSD, aka drive D, was constantly at 100% "active time". I was able to use the "run new task" option in task manager to get to folders/files and command prompt, which works like it normally should.

The PC was working perfectly fine before the power went out, and I have never seen it (or any other computer) have this problem.
I think this might be from dirty power from the outage, but I also did some googling, and it might also just be a problem with the graphics card.

I really need help diagnosing, and hopefully fixing the problem, I have a lot of important files on this computer, and I need it for gaming and work for my classes. Can anyone help me please?

Another thing: if I sit and don't touch the computer for some minutes, occasionally the computer background will show up, and disappear back into the black screen whenever I try to do anything. Also, the windows bar at the bottom will also occasionally appear, but it won't be functional at all, and will disappear when I try to interact with it. The computer also takes around 30-40 minutes just to shut down, similarly to booting up.

---

This is what I mean by "cloning into the background" https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyTeV.jpg

Hey, I fixed the problem. Apparently it was the D drive that was breaking everything, once I removed it my PC works completely fine.

Comment: Put the drive in a carrier, recover what you can and start reinstalling Windows

Comment: Hey, I fixed the problem. Apparently it was the D drive that was breaking everything, once I removed it my PC works completely fine.

Comment: @IsaacOlson.  Then you should add that as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is some serious damage to your system, like the hard drive or other core component. While I cannot pinpoint your exact issue, I think a surge may have caused damage to your system and you should seek repair from a shop.

Comment: Thanks, I was messing around with the computer and disconnected the D drive, and now everything works great. I still don't know how an SSD caused all of these problems, but at least my whole PC isn't toast.